# Using Websocket data on other functions

Tags: python, function, websocket, binance

I am calling websocket functions for particular data and want to use it later on other functions.
However, I am noticing the websocket simply doesnt stop updating and doesnt go further to check the other functions.
I guess this is due to calling ws.run_forever().

What is the alternative? can you help me? Should I create a thread for  the websocket connection?

Thanks

```
import json
import websocket
import os
from math import pi
from itertools import count
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

def on_message(ws,message):
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    cs = json_message
    for coin in cs:
      min_price[coin["s"]] = { "lastPrice": coin["c"], "lowPrice": coin["l"]}
      with open(compare_coins, "w") as file:
        json.dump(min_price, file, indent=4)
    is_candle_closed = candle['x']
    if is_candle_closed:
        print(json.dumps(candle, indent=2))


ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCK, on_open=on_open,on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.keep_running = True

def check_below():
  volatile_coins = {}
  for coin in min_price:
    if float(min_price[coin]["lastPrice"])>=float(min_price[coin]["lowPrice"]):
      volatile_coins[coin] = min_price[coin]["lastPrice"]
  return volatile_coins, len(volatile_coins), min_price
```

Comment: What are your imports? And maybe reduce your code to the websocket problem part?

Comment: My friend. thanks for your answer:
1. Fetching lastPrice and minPrice from the websocket (done)
2. Check if lastprice is the same as minprice

Basically, I think the issue is I need to close the connection to the websocket somewhere in the function. I dont know where

Comment: I meant: please update your question by adding your dependencies + remove the distracting code ;-)

Comment: I fixed it by closing the ws on the on_message function. No idea if this is 100% correct but I leave that for future cases